# How to create a Navigation Property to do a left join in EF 1 / .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-3.5, ef-database-first

I have to create a support library for an legacy .NET 3.5 Application and need to use EF 1 Database First to do a left join.

After some exception, I have readed, that `DefaultIfEmpty()` is not supported by EF 1 and I should possible try to use navigation properties.

Well, I do not understand how can I create a navigation property.

I right clicked my diagram and used *Add new -> Association*:

[image: Association]

Since I do want Many *WAWI_Quittungen* where each entity can or can not have an *OnlineClients* I selected `0..1` to `*`.

However, I do not understand how can I teach the Designer to use `Client` and `ClientNr` to join instead of the primary keys.

I am getting an Exception (translated):

> MappingException: 
>   Entities.Kassenautomat.msl(3,4) : Error 3027: For the followingEntitySet/AssociationSet was not given an association - OnlineClientsWAWI_Quittungen.

I tried to set the MappingDetails as found in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/relationships#create-an-association-mapping), but I only find the primary keys:

[image: Mapping Details]

So how can I add a Navigation Property?

Comment: EF 1,2,3,4,5,6 supports only FK to PK associations

Comment: Oh that's realy bad :( Guess I need to use Linq2SQL then. Thank you